# How to get a taxonomy custom image field URL value

Tags: 8, taxonomy-terms

I've created an image 'field_term_preview' field on the taxonomy vocabulary and trying to get this URL in my custom module:

```
$terms =\Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('taxonomy_term')->loadTree($vid, 0, null, true);

foreach ($terms as $term) {
    if ($term->getName = 'Term with preview')
    {
        foreach ($term->getFields(true) as $field)
        {
            if ($field->getName() == 'field_term_preview')
            {
                var_dump($field->getValue());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This code shows only target_id, alt, height, etc.
[image]

How to get the URL to the preview image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Drupal images are File entities, the `target_id` is the File ID. So...

```
$fid = $field->getValue()[0]['target_id']; // File ID, 

// Note the [0] in the array. We assume there is always going to be 1 image here. 
// If your field allows more than 1 image, you will need to loop through each $field->getValue()

$file = \Drupal\file\Entity\File::load($fid); // load File entity object

$file_url = $file->url(); // get the URL.
```